# Assign stderr of individual command(s) in a pipeline to a variable in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to capture the stderr output to variable in a piped command.
Lets say I have 2 commands piped cmd1 | cmd2
cmd1 is curl command and I have kept cmd2 as a simple echo for test(eg echo "hello")

I have

```
error_message=$(cmd1|cmd2)
```

but when cmd1 fails, error_message is set to the output of cmd2(error_message="hello").
I want the error message of the curl command to be set to the variable.
I have tried

```
error_message=$(cmd1 2>&1|cmd2)
error_message=$(cmd1|cmd2 2>&1)
```

Both of them don't work.

In all I would like the variable to be set to the stderr output of the first failed command in the pipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to connect the standard error of individual pipeline components to the standard output of the pipeline. Below are a few examples demonstrating how it is done.

1. Capture the standard error of all components:

   ```sh
   error_message=$(
     { cmd1 | cmd2 >/dev/null; } 2>&1
   )
   ```
2. Capture the standard error of separate pipeline components (`cmd1` and `cmd3`):

   ```
   error_message=$(
     { cmd1 2>&3 | cmd2 | cmd3 2>&3 >/dev/null; } 3>&1
   )
   ```
3. Capture the standard error of adjacent pipeline components (`cmd1` and `cmd2`):

   ```
   error_message=$(
     { { cmd1 | cmd2; } 2>&3 | cmd3 >/dev/null; } 3>&1
   )
   ```

(In all three examples, the standard output of the pipeline is redirected to `/dev/null`.)